# how to replace xsi:type inside a node in XML?

Tags: c#, regex, xml, replace, deserialization

i have an XML output and there is a problem in de-serialization ex: `MemoItem3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>`
 i need to remove or replace xsi:type="xsd:string" with an empty and be like `MemoItem3 />`

note i tried this but not working:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IO_StrOut) && IO_StrOut.Contains("xsi:type"))
  {

      Regex.Replace(IO_StrOut, @"\s+xsi:type=""\w+""", "");
  };
```

here XML i need to replace any xsi:type

```
<Header>
      <MemoList>
        <MemoItem1 />
        <MemoItem2 />
        <MemoItem3 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
        <MemoItem4 xsi:type="xsd:string">11.1</MemoItem4>
        <MemoItem5 xsi:type="xsd:string">5.0</MemoItem5>
        <MemoItem7 xsi:type="xsd:string">AndroidPhone</MemoItem7>
      </MemoList>
      <User>
        <UserID />
      </User>
      <Service>
        <ServiceID xsi:type="xsd:string">ContactInquiry</ServiceID>
        <ServiceMessageType xsi:type="xsd:string">ContactInquiry</ServiceMessageType>
        <ServiceRequestID xsi:type="xsd:string"></ServiceRequestID>
        <ServiceRequestLanguageCode>EN</ServiceRequestLanguageCode>
        <ServiceResult>
          <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
          <ResultDesc />
        </ServiceResult>
        <ServiceRequestTime>2020-03-02T18:46:22.163+03:00</ServiceRequestTime>
      </Service>
      <CachingAndExpiryControl />
    </Header>
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing during de-serialization

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (32, 6). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined.

Comment: okay. can you add xml and model to the post

Comment: the XML is not valid then ... wrap in `<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">` and should work

Comment: If you have a type then usually you have inherited classes and are missing the Include.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sF1Yyp

Comment: @Selvin i have no idea why this added for those nodes only thats why i wanna remove it

Comment: If it is there, it is for a good reason.  You should not be trying to remove.

Comment: @jdweng it should be removed because it make a problem at de-serialization

Comment: If you are having issue contact the people who generated the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the deserialization but [the regex seems wrong](https://regexr.com/4vgbp) as ':' is not a "word" matched with "\w".

Maybe [this](https://regexr.com/4vgau) could match ?